# Rsync from Linux to Windows SFTP Server

Tags: linux, windows, sftp, rsync

I'm trying to sync documents to an Windows SFTP server via RSYNC on a Linux Machine.

This is my command

```
rsync -e ssh /home/antony/Documents/Test user1@172.20.1.18:Test
```

This is the error

```
exec request failed on channel 0
rsync connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes recieved so far)[sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]
```

Comment: You can not run `rsync` on top of SFTP. You need an `rsync` server running on the target machine or alternatively a SSH server and the `rsync` executable there.

Comment: If you want a command line solution, you can use scp which doesn't rely on rsync protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The above may happen for several different reasons.

Maybe the SSH subsystem of rsync is refusing the server key, but this is unlikely because from your description seems like the server is "cutting" the connection, not the client.

Another possibility is that there is no SSH/SFTP server listening on the default port on 172.20.1.18

Or maybe password authentication is not enabled on the server, and you need to authenticate via PKI using a key that you (on the client side) do not have...

In any case, the best thing to do is to double check with the administrator who has configured the server side.